# Comparing string read from csv file

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to compare string read from csv file in if condition. Below is the sample code I have written:

```
export IFS="~"
while read a b c
do
    echo "line Num:$a"
    if [ "$b"=="sat" ];then
        echo "Its saturday"
        echo $c
    elif [ "$b"=="sun" ];then
        echo "Its sunday"
        echo $c
    else
        echo "Its weekday"
        echo $c
    fi
done < "$1"
```

Below is the csv file:

```
1~sat~enjoy
2~sun~enjoy
3~mon~work
4~tue~work
5~sun~enjoy
```

Below is the output I'm getting:

```
line Num:1
Its saturday
enjoy
line Num:2
Its saturday
enjoy
line Num:3
Its saturday
enjoy
line Num:4
Its saturday
enjoy
line Num:5
Its saturday
enjoy
```

Needed the below output instead:

```
line Num:1
Its saturday
enjoy
line Num:2
Its sunday
enjoy
line Num:3
Its weekday
work
line Num:4
Its weekday
work
line Num:5
Its sunday
enjoy
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for indenting that code!

Comment: Which shell are you using? Bash? Bourne shell?

Comment: csv file with \r endings? Try converting your csv file, with `dos2unix` or `tr -d "\r"`. Perhaps you can change `done < "$1"` into `done < <( tr -d "\r" < "$1")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
export IFS="~"
while read a b c
do
echo "line Num:$a"
if [ "$b" = "sat" ];then
echo "Its saturday"
echo $c
elif [ "$b" = "sun" ];then
echo "Its sunday"
echo $c
else
echo "Its weekday"
echo $c
fi
done < "$1"
```

do not use `"$foo"=="$bar"` as bash will only see one token.

you can also try

```
case "$b" in
sat) echo "It's saturday" ;;
sun) echo "It's sunday" ;;
*) echo "It's weekday" ;;
esac
echo $c
```